# How to find the power required to 2 for a known value in Python

Tags: python

Could someone please tell me a method to find power of `2` required to obtain a known value. For example, let's say I need to find the power of two which gives the value 32. In other words, if I know a certain value, how to find the power of two which give that value.

```
if the given value is 64 how to get the power of two as 8
```

I have searched whether similar questions have been asked in stackoverflow before, but unfortunately I could not find any.  At the moment I have nothing on my hand as an attempt taken, sorry for that. 
Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import math

print (math.log(64, 2))
print (2**math.log(64, 2))
```

Output:

```
6
64
```

Comment: Thank you very much Synthase. This is the second time you helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python math module's `log2()` function. Here is the code:

```
import math
print (math.log2(64))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support DapperDuck.

Comment: No problem! Just as a note, according to this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/log-functions-python/), `log2(x)`displays a more accurate output than `log(x,2)` for logarithms with base 2.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> x, n = 0,64
>>> while n! = 1:
    x += 1
    n >>= 1

    
>>> x
6
```

Comment: Thank you very for your help and consideration Yang Liu.